# in a pointed quasicategory, why is $X \simeq cofib(X[-1] \to 0)$? Answer: it's not

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, higher-category-theory

$\require{AMscd}$
Let $C$ be an pointed $\infty$-category (by which I mean quasicategory) admitting cofibers. For an object $X \in C$, why is $X \simeq cofib(X[-1] \to 0)$?

Here $X[-1]=\Omega X$ is an object such that

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    X[-1] @>a>> 0\\
    @V b V V @VV c V\\
    0 @>>d> X
    \end{CD}

is a pullback square. If $C$ is stable, then that means this is also a pushout square, and so then I see why. But in Higher Algebra Lemma 1.1.2.10, C is just a pointed infinity category, not necessarily stable. I'm sure the answer is incredibly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly not true for an arbitrary pointed $\infty$-category with cofibers.  For instance, in the category of pointed spaces, this would mean that the canonical map $\Sigma\Omega X\to X$ is a weak equivalence for all (nice) pointed spaces $X$, which is very false (for a simple example, take $X=S^0$).  However, the statement of Lemma 1.1.2.10 has an extra hypothesis: that the suspension functor is an equivalence on $C$.